# Listing the processes running on one's computer in Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, process

Is there a cross-platform way to list the processes running on one's computer through a python script? For Unix based system "ps -ef" works, but I am new to Python and don't know a way to write something that would work across any platform.

Thanks!

Comment: May be if elaborate on the problem your trying to solve, we could help you better. (Why do you need to look up processes cross-platform?)

Comment: Just write a small app that depends on the processes information and want to make ti cross-platform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python itself doesn't offer any such functionality. On PyPI, there is the [enumprocess](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enumprocess/0.1) package, which supposedly helps; there is also the [PSI](http://www.psychofx.com/psi/trac/wiki/) package. I haven't personally used any of them.

Answer (score 1):

While [PSI](https://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home) page lists some alternatives, what you need is [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). It is the only one that supports Windows, or as it states on a home page:

> Linux, Windows, OSX and FreeBSD both
>   32-bit and 64-bit with Python versions
>   from 2.4 to 3.2.

Comment: 'psutil' is great, but the 'name' method is slow (at least on Windows).  Check out this nice piece of code: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587036/alternative-to-psutil-processpid-name)