# Alternative to psutil.Process(pid).name

Tags: python, performance, pywin32

I have measured the performance of `psutil.Process(pid).name` and it turns out that it is more than ten times slower than for example `psutil.Process(pid).exe`. Because the last one of these functions requires different privileges over the path, I cannot just just extract the filename from the path. My question is: Are there any alternatives to `psutil.Process(pid).name`, which does the same?

Comment: The psutil library isn't that large.  The only other method in there that may be useful is Process(pid).cmdline (if cmdline[0] is the exe) but I'd guess that has the same access restrictions as the exe function.  Are you looking for a non-psutil way of doing this?  If so, what is your OS?  You could always dig up a faster way for your specific OS and rewrite the name function for psutil.  If this is a request for the psutil library you could file an issue on the project.

Comment: My OS is Windows. I will probably file a request, but it would be nice to have a solution for them already.

Comment: Tell us your exact OS version including SP and patchlevel, and your Python version. Also, post your timing numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned this is for windows.  I took a look at what psutil does for windows.  It looks like psutil.Process().name is using the windows tool help API.  If you look at psutil's Process code and trace .name, it goes to get_name() in [process_info.c](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c).  It is looping through all the pids on your system until it finds the one you're looking for.  I think this may be a limitation of the toolhelp API.  But this is why it's slower than .exe, which uses a different API path, that (as you pointed out), requires additional privilege.

The solution I came up with is to use ctypes and ctypes.windll to call the windows ntapi directly.  It only needs PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, which is different than PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS:

```
import ctypes
import os.path

# duplicate the UNICODE_STRING structure from the windows API

class UNICODE_STRING(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ('Length', ctypes.c_short),
      ('MaximumLength', ctypes.c_short),
      ('Buffer', ctypes.c_wchar_p)
    ]

# args

pid = 8000 # put your pid here

# define some constants; from windows API reference

MAX_TOTAL_PATH_CHARS = 32767
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400 
PROCESS_IMAGE_FILE_NAME = 27

# open handles

ntdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('ntdll.dll')
process = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
  False, pid)

# allocate memory

buflen = (((MAX_TOTAL_PATH_CHARS + 1) * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_wchar)) +
  ctypes.sizeof(UNICODE_STRING))
buffer = ctypes.c_char_p(' ' * buflen) 

# query process image filename and parse for process "name"

ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess(process, PROCESS_IMAGE_FILE_NAME, buffer,
  buflen, None)
pustr = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.POINTER(UNICODE_STRING))
print os.path.split(pustr.contents.Buffer)[-1]

# cleanup

ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(ntdll._handle)
```

Comment: I will look into this shortly, if it works, then you are a genious! Maybe you want to contribute the code to psutil?

Comment: I can confirm that this works and is about 10x faster than psutil's 'name' method.  Thank you!

Comment: **This is brilliant.** I've been searching for ageless ages for a pure-Python solution retrieving Windows process metadata *without* expensive process forking (e.g., to parse `tlist.exe` output). This must have taken positively forever to cobble together! Bravo. That said... cleanup should ideally be embedded within the `finally:` clause of a `try:` block to avoid resource leaks in edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

As of psutil 1.1.0 this problem has been fixed, see https://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/detail?id=426